# Yii2 Dynamic Form update Action is not working

Tags: php, yii2

I like to explain my problem clearly,
Am using [wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform](https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform)
Here `create actio`n is working perfectly, but in `update` action [image: problem]

In the code which i marked, i don't know what i need to do, i dont have such field `(addresses)` in `customer` table. am stuck on that.

suppose if i create a variable in model like `public $addressess`, it makes me the reload the table again, and that cause while update the same form, data's getting reload and form viewing as empty without empty,

if create a function on that name, i don't know what to write on that..
Am simply using code like this

```
public function getaddressess()
{

}
```

Create Action Code

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $modelCustomer = new Customer;
        $modelsAddress = [new Address];
        if ($modelCustomer->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

            $modelsAddress = Model::createMultiple(Address::classname());
            Model::loadMultiple($modelsAddress, Yii::$app->request->post());

            // ajax validation
            if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
                Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
                return ArrayHelper::merge(
                    ActiveForm::validateMultiple($modelsAddress),
                    ActiveForm::validate($modelCustomer)
                );
            }

            // validate all models
            $valid = $modelCustomer->validate();
            $valid = Model::validateMultiple($modelsAddress) && $valid;

            if ($valid) {
                $transaction = \Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
                try {
                    if ($flag = $modelCustomer->save(false)) {
                        foreach ($modelsAddress as $modelAddress) {
                            $modelAddress->customer_id = $modelCustomer->id;
                            if (! ($flag = $modelAddress->save(false))) {
                                $transaction->rollBack();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if ($flag) {
                        $transaction->commit();
                        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $modelCustomer->id]);
                    }
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $transaction->rollBack();
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'modelCustomer' => $modelCustomer,
            'modelsAddress' => (empty($modelsAddress)) ? [new Address] : $modelsAddress
        ]);
    }
```

Help me to sort out this problem

Comment: Am also facing the same problem, answer would be appreciated...

Comment: what errors you got? be more specific.

Comment: Please provide alse the actionCreate code ...

Comment: Getting unknown property: backend\models\Importpending::addresses

Comment: please see above i have updated my question

Comment: It should be "getAddresses()" instead of "getaddresses()".

Answer (score 2):

`$modelsAddress=$modelCustomer->addresses` in that example mean array of related `Address()` instances

```
 public function actionCreate()
        {
            $modelCustomer = new Customer;
            $modelsAddress = $this->getaddressess($modelCustomer->id);

    //...................
   }



    public function getaddressess($id)
    {
      $model = Address::find()->where(['id' => $id])->all();
      return $model;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

from

```
 public function getaddressess($id)
{
  $model = Address::find()->where(['id' => $id])->all();
  return $model;
}
```

Shared above you will also need to add

on your Update view file :

```
'model' => $model,
'modelsAddress'=>$modelsAddress,
```

Hope this helps. It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

It should be `getAddresses()` instead of `getaddresses()` (although both could work, I'd go with the first one to meet conventions). Or you could set a `public $addresses` if you don't need extra encapsulation.

```
suppose if i create a variable in model like public $addressess, it makes me the reload the table again, and that cause while update the same form, data's getting reload and form viewing as empty without empty,
```

I think you have a validation issue - no validator to mark the field as safe and you see it as empty after posting.

1. Add `public $addresses` to your Customer model.
2. Add "addresses" to your [validation rules](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html) as safe (or more appropriate validator). This way after posting the form, it probably won't render empty.

Comment: while doing validation for $addressess also empty field is rendering when am update

Answer (score 0):

This line code --->    **$modelsAddress = $modelCustomer->addresses;**

is get from **model** for **customer** at line ---> **public function getAddresses()**

this public function line code is code for get array **related table** from active record method on yii2.

Answer (score 0):

$modelCustomer->addresses the word addresses should come from the $modelCustomer model you must have a relationship to the other table where you add the multiple values. In my example described in the video I have two tables po table and po_items table po_items table has foreign key of po_id. So when you make the Models using gii you will get a relationship in the model that is what you have to use instead of the addresses.

the relationship according my database should be - poItems you will see this at line 14

Answer (score 0):

Add this to Customer Model

```
 public function getAddresses(){
        return $this->hasMany(Address::className(), ['id' => 'id']);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsH96.png)In Po.php models:

```
public function getPoItems()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PoItem::className(), ['po_id' => 'id']);
}
```

In PoController.php

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    //$modelsPoItem = [new PoItem];
    $modelsPoItem = $model->poItems;

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) 
    {
                  
        $oldIDs = ArrayHelper::map($modelsPoItem, 'id', 'id');
        $modelsPoItem = Model::createMultiple(PoItem::classname(), $modelsPoItem);
        Model::loadMultiple($modelsPoItem, Yii::$app->request->post());
        $deletedIDs = array_diff($oldIDs, array_filter(ArrayHelper::map($modelsPoItem, 'id', 'id')));


        // validate all models
        $valid = $model->validate();
        $valid = Model::validateMultiple($modelsPoItem) && $valid;

        if ($valid) {
            $transaction = \Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
            try {
                if ($flag = $model->save(false)) {
                    if (! empty($deletedIDs)) 
                    {
                        PoItem::deleteAll(['id' => $deletedIDs]);
                    }
                    foreach ($modelsPoItem as $modelPoItem) 
                    {
                        $modelPoItem->po_id = $model->id;
                        if (! ($flag = $modelPoItem->save(false))) {
                            $transaction->rollBack();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if ($flag) {
                    $transaction->commit();
                    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $transaction->rollBack();
            }
        }

    }

    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
        'modelsPoItem' => (empty($modelsPoItem)) ? [new PoItem] : $modelsPoItem
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Not working is not a deal for us... what is not working exactly? what error do you get?